# Why do the members of my list get overwritten with the last member of said list?

Tags: c#, list, c#-4.0, nested-lists

I am trying to write a program that prints out (in a string variable) the following information about an mdb database:

Table Name
Total number of columns of the table

List of columns as follows:

Column Name:
Column Data Type:

To accomplish this I used two custom types (public classes) and of course, lists. Here is the code I have so far (which by the way has been adjusted not in small part thanks to questions and answers gathered here):

Here are the classes I created to define the two new types I am using:

```
public class ClmnInfo
{
    public string strColumnName { get; set; }
    public string strColumnType { get; set; }
}

public class TblInfo
{
    public string strTableName { get; set; }
    public int intColumnsQty { get; set; }
    public List<ClmnInfo> ColumnList { get; set; }

}
```

Here is the code that actually gets the data. Keep in mind that I am using OleDB to connect to the actual data and everything works fine, except for the problem I will describe below.
As a sample, I am currently testing this code with a simple 1 table db, containing 12 columns of type string save for 1 int32 (Long Int in Access).

```
//Here I declare and Initialize all relevant variables and Lists
TblInfo CurrentTableInfo = new TblInfo();
ClmnInfo CurrentColumnInfo = new ClmnInfo();
List<TblInfo> AllTablesInfo = new List<TblInfo>();

 //This loop iterates through each table obtained and imported previously in the program
int i = 0;
foreach (DataTable dt in dtImportedTables.Tables)
{


    CurrentTableInfo.strTableName = Globals.tblSchemaTable.Rows[i][2].ToString(); //Gets the name of the current table
    CurrentTableInfo.intColumnsQty = dt.Columns.Count; //Gets the total number of columns in the current table
    CurrentTableInfo.ColumnList = new List<ClmnInfo>(); //Initializes the list which will house all of the columns 

    //This loop iterates through each column in the current table
    foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
    {
        CurrentColumnInfo.ColumnName = dc.ColumnName;  // Gets the current column name
        CurrentColumnInfo.ColumnType = dc.DataType.Name; // Gets the current column data type

        CurrentTableInfo.ColumnList.Add(CurrentColumnInfo); // adds the information just obtained as a member of the columns list contained in CurrentColumnInfo 
     }
//BAD INSTRUCTION FOLLOWS:

        AllTablesInfo.Add(CurrentTableInfo); //This SHOULD add The collection of column_names and column_types in a "master" list containing the table name, the number of columns, and the list of columns
    }
```

I debugged the code and watched all variables. It works great (the table name and column quantity gets registered correctly, as well as the list of column_names, column_types for that table), but when the "bad" instruction gets executed, the contents of AllTablesInfo are not at all what they should be. 
The table name is correct, as well as the number of columns, and the columns list even has 12 members as it should have, but each member of the list is the same, namely the LAST column of the database I am examining. Can anyone explain to me why CurrentTableInfo gets overwritten in this manner when it is added to the AllTablesInfo list?

Comment: Ah, mutation... Thou hast stifled many a programmer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're creating a *single* `TblInfo` object, and then changing the properties on each iteration. Your list contains lots of references to the same object. Just move this line:

```
TblInfo CurrentTableInfo = new TblInfo();
```

to the *inside* of the first loop, and this line:

```
ClmnInfo CurrentColumnInfo = new ClmnInfo();
```

inside the nested `foreach` loop, so that you're creating *new* instances on each iteration.

Next:

- **Important**
  Make sure you understand *why* it was failing before. Read my article on [references](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/references.html) if you're not sure how objects and references (and value types) work in C#
- Use `camelCased` names instead of `CamelCased` ones for local variables
- Consider using an object initializer for the `ClmnInfo`
- Change your type names to avoid unnecessary abbreviation (`TableInfo`, `ColumnInfo`)
- Change your property names to avoid pseudo-Hungarian notation, and make them `PascalCased`
- Consider rewriting the whole thing as a LINQ query (relatively advanced)

The pre-LINQ changes would leave your code looking something like this:

```
List<TableInfo> tables = new List<TableInfo>();

int i = 0;
foreach (DataTable dt in dtImportedTables.Tables)
{
    TableInfo table = new TableInfo
    {
        Name = Globals.tblSchemaTable.Rows[i][2].ToString(),
        // Do you really need this? Won't it be the same as Columns.Count?
        ColumnCount = dt.Columns.Count,
        Columns = new List<ColumnInfo>()
    };

    foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
    {
        table.Columns.Add(new ColumnInfo {
                            Name = dc.ColumnName,
                            Type = dc.DataType.Name
                          });
    }
    tables.Add(table); 
    // I assume you meant to include this?
    i++;
}
```

With LINQ:

```
List<TableInfo> tables = 
    dtImportedTables.Tables.Zip(Globals.tblSchemaTable.Rows.AsEnumerable(),
        (table, schemaRow) => new TableInfo {
            Name = schemaRow[2].ToString(),
            // Again, only if you really need it
            ColumnCount = table.Columns.Count,
            Columns = table.Columns.Select(column => new ColumnInfo {
                        Name = column.ColumnName,
                        Type = column.DataType.Name
                      }).ToList()
        }
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you, you are of course right, and as you can tell I am still as green as they come with c# and its _objects_ and _instances_. Thank you so much for your great help!

Answer (score 1):

You have only created one instance of TblInfo.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you only have a single instance of TblInfo, which you keep updating in your loop and then add another reference to it to the List.  Thus your list has many references to the same object in memory.

Move the creation of the CurrentTableInfo instance inside the for loop.